# How to configure SQL Server 2014 Database using MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I am trying to connect my SQL Server 2014 Database With my MVC Application.

My code is as follows:

Model class `Category.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GetImage.Models
{
    public class Category
    {

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My context class `CategoryContext.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GetImage.Models
{
    public class CategoryContext
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;
        SqlCommand command = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Spencers"].ConnectionString;

        //Get Categories
        public List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            List<Category> categories = null;
            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (command=new SqlCommand("uspGetCategories",connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            categories = new List<Category>();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                categories.Add(
                                    new Category() { 
                                    CategoryID=int.Parse(reader["CategoryID"].ToString()),
                                    CategoryName=reader["CategoryName"].ToString(),
                                    Picture=reader["Picture"] as byte[]
                                    }
                                    );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return categories;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-GetImage-20150411072900.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GetImage-20150411072900;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--Own DB Connection-->
    <add name="Spencers" 
         connectionString="Data SourceVIKASHPC\vikash;Initial Catalog=Spencers;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
```

**Note:**

From the above codes, I am trying to connect with my SQL Server 2014 database.

By default, ASP.NET MVC application is connecting with the `localDB`. I don't want to connect with `localDB`. Instead, I want to connect to my SQL Server 2014 database.

Please help me to get rid off this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string is valid. I see a missing `=` after Data Source. Also you might need to provide authentication details

```
connectionString="Data Source=VIKASHPC\vikash;Initial Catalog=Spencers;
                                 User Id=yourSqlUser;Password=yourSqlPassword"
```

Assuming your SQL server instance name is `VIKASHPC\vikash`, which is up and running. Also make sure the sql user has access to your database.(try to login as that user from SSMS)

Check https://www.connectionstrings.com/ to see valid connection string formats.

Comment: I don't have username and password. I am using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Update your connection string to reflect that then.